# Azure Application Insights - Parse string in format dd/MM/yyyy to datetime

Tags: azure-application-insights

The question is pretty direct: how can i parse a string like `"23/12/2017"` (dd/MM/yyyy) to a datetime?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're asking about Application Insights Analytics this should do a trick:

todatetime("2015-12-24") == datetime(2015-12-24)

https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Scalar-functions/todatetime()

Comment: tks, but thats not enough... i don't have a date on that friendly format, what i have is `24/12/2015`... i know i can substring it and manipulate the pieces to a workable format, i just wanted to know if theres a more direct way